# Exception when loading partial xml data into xsd dataset

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd

I have the following .xsd code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="MyDataSet">
  <xs:element name="Row">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Number" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="Item" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Comment" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And the following .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<MyDataSet>
  <Row>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Item>first</Item>
  </Row> 
</MyDataSet>
```

Since the "Comment" tag is missing in the xml file, I get an exception when running:

```
MyDataSet myDataSet = new MyDataSet();
myDataSet.ReadXml(xmlFilePath);
```

The exception is: "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints."

How can I define the .xsd to be able to receive partial xml data and fill null or any default value when a tag is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it... I needed to add the attribute "Nillable" with the value of "true" to the fields that may not arrive in the xml.